# Is there a Java YAML library you might recommend?

Tags: java, yaml

I am looking for a Java YAML library (I defo don't want to use Jackson-YAML for a variety of reasons), and was wondering if there was any that people recommend.

Thanks!

Comment: That might very much depend on what features you'd expect from it. Just "Java YAML library" is a bit meager for objective and good answers ;)

Comment: Enumerate those reasons why Jackson-YAML fails you so as to explain your specific needs.

Comment: Please read [ask], and give us your requirements - help us to help you. As it stands, this question is ridiculously broad.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you think is wrong with Jackson-YAML, so my recommendations might contain libraries with the same problems.

[SnakeYAML](https://github.com/asomov/snakeyaml-engine) looks like a good option. Alternatively, there's [Camel](https://github.com/decorators-squad/camel), but it's not been updated in four months and (from the commit history) receives irregular updates.